# Caching of FileResult actions in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action which returns a FileResult (which is a png image). I would dearly like for browsers to cache the result, because it doesn't change for a given request uri.

I have used routing to make the uri look like this-

```
http://localhost:6094/Map/Tiles/1.0.0/none/2/5/5.png
```

And in the action method, i call:-

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

In Fiddler, I can observe that the response has the:-

```
Cache-control: public
```

header. Yet, subsequent requests for the same map tile look like this:-

```
    GET http://localhost:6094/Map/Tiles/1.0.0/none/2/5/5.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6094
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.34 Safari/536.11
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:6094/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

And so result in a 200 response, and the transfer of data.

Any idea why Chrome is not bothering to cache my data?

thanks

slip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the OutputCache attribute? This should work fine for you but specify it's lifetime.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

ex

```
[OutputCache(Duration=84600)]
```

Comment: OutputCache caches this ON THE SERVER, no on the client

Comment: @SergeShultz: [OutputCache(Duration = 84600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)] would only cache on the server. However, the default value for Location is OutputCacheLocation.Any which means the output will be cached on the server, but also the Cache-Control header will be set to public so the response can be cached on proxys and by the browser.